# Inserting SVGs with conflicting IDs using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, svg

SVGs inserted into a document using javascript look like gibberish because they have symbols with conflicting IDs inside them. For instance, these two different svg files

http://filebin.ca/1LMtJr5zc2x/svg1.svg

http://filebin.ca/1LN9F5ZPIbH/svg2.svg

When inserted into a document with javascript*, one of them looks wrong (in my case the a's turned into x's). If you open the SVG files with a text editor you'll see they both have a line like this

```
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
```

So I'm guessing the browser sees the second svg reference "glyph0-0" and uses the one defined by the *first* svg. Is there some way to tell the browser "symbols defined inside an <svg> only matter there"? Like restricting the scope of symbols.

<img> tags which point to those two files don't have this problem. However I'm not using that solution because then the server would have to keep a bunch of files around and keep track of when they can be thrown away. With my current solution the browser has the SVGs in memory and they're gone when the window closes.

*with XMLHttpRequest, I fetch a dynamically-generated SVG file, clone the root <svg> tag and append it to the document.

Comment: As far as I know Firefox is the only browser to support SVG graphics. Is this correct and are you fine with that?

Comment: Nope, Firefox really is NOT the only browser supporting SVG. http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: Could you use `<img>` tags with inline `data` URIs representing each SVG document?

Comment: That could work, I'll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs are always global to a document, and non-unique IDs are considered invalid according to the HTML spec. If you require two symbols to have the same id, try using "class" instead of "id". You could also do some regex pre-processing of the SVG string to adjust the IDs so they're unique.

Comment: I see. I might use MathML instead of latex->pdf->svg, seems like less hassle.

Comment: @eternauta3k, OP; indeed. I'd use something like PHP/SimpleXML to iterate over one of the documents and change each `id` to have a unique prefix, say an MD5 hash. The two docs can then be merged with no chance of uniqueness conflicts.